# Bootstrap NavSide with Scroll and Dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, sidebar

This is my first time on SlackOverflow, i hope that you can help me.
I'm trying to achieve something tricky regarding my skill on development and specifically on Bootstrap.

I've created a template with dual Navbar (top and left).
The left one is a fixed navside where there is 3 kind of experience : Expanded, Not Expanded, Not visible.

As you can see, my Expanded NavSide is working perfectly with Scrollbar and Dropdown inside the nav

[Expanded SideBar with Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUcBZ.png)

The not visible experience is also working perfectly.

[Not Visible SideBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDh25.png)

When i'm working with my not expanded SideBar, everything is perfect if i don't have too many item menus. If i have too much items i can't scroll on the Sidebar because i've only activated my css for expanded js.

[Not Expanded SideBar without Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb5PV.png)

Where is the issue ? I want to keep the same experience for the not Expanded version with Dropdown displayed on the right of my navside. But if i put the overflow-y scroll on my navbar, the dropdown on the right side is not displayed anymore (but the scroll is working well).

[Not Expanded Sidebar with scroll but no Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m3lS.png)

Any idea if what i'm trying to achieve is possible ?

I can share my code if needed :)

Many thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please share minimal code so that we can help better rather than building same from scratch.